# Create Image Slider Like Nivo Slider With Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I'd like to build image slider like Nivo slider with Adobe Flash Builder.

i'd like to have image controls, image titles displayed above the image(like layers in flash).

i'd like to read the data from xml.

i'd like to have nice transitions between images.

mayebe u can provide tutorial or source code.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer control, and load the images from an xml file, like loading it from a xml Web service.

Then define a transition, that you fires every time the new image was loaded.

When the user chooses to scroll the images manually, then stop the timer.

Just click on the Add Data menu, and Select XML (local file), and follow the wizard.

Samples: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/502852

On the loaded even of the loaded XML data file, start the timer, that will start to load the images.

Define a transitions, using this tutorial as a sample:

http://hkcoding.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/flex-image-transitions-from-xml-using-the-greensock-library-tutorial/

Get some more ides from this component: http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

This should get you started, somehow.